# Django: Model function is not returning proper value in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

have the `bookingrecordsView` view in which I fetch all reservations made by a user. I added a model function `is_pending()` that fetches a reservation instance, checks whether the `date_to` field has passed or not, and returns a string. The view that fetches the reservations:

```
def bookingrecordsView(request):
     rsv = Reservation.objects.filter(user=request.user)
     return render(request, 'booking_history_page.html', {'rsv': rsv})
```

And the function that checks the date:

```
class Reservation (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_from = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
    date_to = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
    time_from = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
    time_to = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
    destination=models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, verbose_name="Where will you go")
    chosen_vehicle=models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank=False, default='')
    booking_time=models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now)
    garage = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default='')
    area = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default='')

    @property
    Def is_pending(self):
        if self.date_to < datetime.date.today():
             return "Pending"
        else:
            return "Over"`
```

This is my template snippet:

```
{% for r in rsv %}
     <tr>
         <td>{{ r.id }}</td> 
         <td>{{ r.date_from }} - {{ r.date_to }}</td>
         <td>{{ r.time_from }} - {{ r.time_to }}</td>
         <td>{{ r.chosen_vehicle }}</td>
         <td>{{ r.garage }}</td>
         <td>{{ r.destination }}</td>
         <td>{{ r.is_pending }}</td>
      </tr>
 {% endfor %}`
```

Now, for all the bookings, even those passed months earlier, this status is always returning 'Pending'.

How do I get the correct return value for every `Reservation` instance from `is_pending()` function and pass it accordingly to the template?

Comment: Can you show all model fields? (maybe you have is_pending field) This code looks right (only some typos).

Comment: Yes, I edited my post.

Comment: When time zone support is enabled, you should compare with time-zone-aware datetime objects. Use timzone.now() from the django.utils package.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: For debug purpose try to select specific Reservation (in the view for example) and print `r.date_to`, `r.is_pending` and `datetime.date.today()`. The code does not seem to be wrong, so, it's data, or render, or something else we don't see here. The page or dataset may be cached. If this is happening on a remote server or a virtual machine - check current time on it.

Comment: Ok, things got a bit complicated.  This makes sense now. Thanks.